# Working with google adwords api

Tags: google-ads-api

What i need to do to use Google AdWords API? Is it real that i must register at My Client Center, pay money and pass stupid tests on google testing service?

Answer (score 10):

in order to use AdWords API, you need to:

1. have a regular Google AdWords account (not My Client Center - MCC one) with campaigns
2. have an MCC account... which cannot have campaigns but have an access to API
3. link your regular AdWords account with the MCC account
4. ask for API access from your MCC Account (My Profile section)
5. pay for API use per Google's [rate sheet](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/ratesheet.html)

... you **can** apply for free API usage, however this does come with a cost. This is where you need to do those stupid tests to get recognized as Certified Partner and fulfill some other [requirements](http://www.google.com/adwords/api/preferredpricing/requirements.html). And yes, you need to pay for these tests (last time I checked, it was $50 per test, there are about 4 of them for AdWords altogether, don't know how many you need to pass to get certified though).

P.S.: those 2 accounts (AdWords and MCC) cannot be combined and for some reason only the MCC one has access to API... wierd but that goes "by design" according to API Support (can't find the link at the moment).

Comment: You need to connect MCC account with your google adword account. And by using MCC account create developer token.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Adwords API without having a MCC or passing any tests, even WITHOUT having an Adwords account, by using the Adwords API sandbox
http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/sandbox.html

Of course this is to be used only for developing and testing purposes..

Answer (score 0):

For getting Google AdWords API access you do not need to give any test.

Google adwords api is free for basic access but billing detail you need to

provide to google adwords.

you can refer this link for sign Up process and how to get approve token,

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup?hl=en